# Ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p}]$ factorise uniquely

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to show that the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p}]$ factorise uniquely.

In know that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p}]$ is not a UFD in general. I also know that, for Dedekind rings, non-zero proper ideals have unique factorisation as a product of non-zero prime ideals. I think I just need to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p}]$ is a Dedekind ring.

Is that the case? If so, how to I show it? If not, what do I need to show?

Comment: "Just" show $\;\Bbb Z[\zeta_p]\;$ is the ring of algebraic integers of the number field $\;\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)\;$ . Then it automatically follows it is a Dedekind ring.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You may want to try this: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter7.pdf  It is not trivial and can be lengthy to show such a thing.

Comment: For the proof of unique factorization of ideals in rings of integers, the main step is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition and the fact that  if $\mathcal{P}$ is a prime ideal then $mathcal{O}_K/ \mathcal{P}$ is an integral domain with finitely many elements and hence a field.

Comment: The simpler example is $w =i \sqrt{5}, \mathcal{O}_K= \mathbb{Z}[w]$ whose class group has two elements : $(1)$ and $(2,1+w)$, so its ideals are of the form $(a), a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ or $(a,a\frac{1+w}{2}), a \in \mathcal{O}_K$

Answer (score 0):

For the proof of unique factorization of ideals in ring of integers, I think the main steps are :

- [$\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$ is Noetherian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem) so that $\mathcal{O}_K= \mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I$ is Noetherian
- The [primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition) in Noetherian rings
- If $\mathcal{P}$ is a prime ideal then $\mathcal{O}_K/ \mathcal{P}$ is an integral domain with finitely many elements, hence it is a field.
- Projecting in those finite fields, it follows that the primary ideals are powers of prime ideals and the [decomposition is unique](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf)

Comment: [Understanding the proof (via primary decomposition) the “ideal factorization theorem” in Dedekind domains](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055884/understanding-the-proof-via-primary-decomposition-the-ideal-factorization-the)